# image logo over TOC in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I know I can insert a logo or image at the top of HTML report rendered using knitr with *in_header/before_body* options

```
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      before_body: header.Rhtml
```

My guess is: how to render logo over floating TOC?

```
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    collapsed: false
    ??????
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You got a few options here and I will outline two of them

**1. Use the CSS pseudo element `before`**

The following snippet will add the stackoverflow logo just above the first TOC element and within the TOC box:

```
<style>
#TOC {
  background: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a");
  background-size: contain;
  padding-top: 80px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Here you will have to adjust the `padding-top` definition depending on your logo. The result looks more or less like this:

[image]

**2. Add a new DOM element inside the TOC column**

Another way is to use jQuery first in order to add a new DOM element that will contain the image:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TOC').parent().prepend('<div id=\"nav_logo\"><img src=\"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a\"></div>');
  });
</script>
```

Here, when the document has finished loading, we select the element with the id `TOC`, then move up to its parent element (the column `div`) and then prepend a new `div` with the id `nav_logo` containing the image. Sounds more complicated than it actually is.
Now we only have to edit the styles for this new div with some CSS again:

```
<style>
#nav_logo {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Here the resulting document looks like this:

[image]

For details on CSS I would refer you to the big search engines which in turn will most probably refer you to https://www.w3schools.com.

If I would have to pick, I would go with the second attempt. Pseudo elements are not always reliable across browsers. And it also looks better :)

Comment: I like the first solution, works great. However, how to use a local image and not a web one? When I replace the link with full path to the image on my hard drive, things work just fine. But when I upload the rmarkdown document on a server and call it from a Shiny app (changing the path to the image on the server), I just get a blank rectangle.

Comment: Cannot try it out. But I guess its just a matter of the correct. Anyhow, you could also encode your image in base64 code and include in the document itself.

Comment: Encoding it to base64 worked perfectly using https://www.base64-image.de/, I included the generated string between the quotes and it did the magic. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This solution (#2) works great for me, but when I have the TOC float down so it always is in the top left corner, the logo remains at the top of the page. is there a simple addition that could have the logo float with the TOC?

Comment: Solution #1 is harder to get the padding to look right but it doesn't float away when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

To enable a logo that floats with TOC during scrolling in solution (#2) from [@Martin Schmelzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849516/10675310) prepend `nav_logo` DOM element containing the image to `TOC` using jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TOC').parent().prepend('<div id=\"nav_logo\"><img src=\"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a\"></div>');
  });
</script>
```

And then add `position: fixed` to `nav_logo` and `margin-top: 100px` to `TOC` in CSS:

```
<style>
#TOC {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#nav_logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Adjust `nav_logo` `width` as necessary.